# How to set the layout in the updated version of plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to plot a simple graphic using the new version of plotly but I keep getting the following error

> Error in UseMethod("layout") :    no applicable method for 'layout'
>   applied to an object of class "character"

This is how my code looks like:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

year <- c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)
amt <- c(11, 16, 21, 27, 33, 37, 43, 54, 68, 94, 128, 170, 213, 258, 307, 348, 385)

data <- data.frame(year, amt)

data$year <- factor(data$year, levels = data[["year"]])

xaxis <- list(title = "Years",
          showline = TRUE,
          showgrid = FALSE,
          showticklabels = TRUE,
          linecolor = 'black',
          linewidth = 1,
          autotick = FALSE,
          ticks = 'outside',
          tickcolor = 'black',
          tickwidth = 2,
          ticklen = 5,
          tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                          size = 10,
                          color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))

yaxis <- list(title = "Years",
          showline = TRUE,
          showgrid = FALSE,
          showticklabels = TRUE,
          linecolor = 'black',
          linewidth = 1,
          autotick = FALSE,
          ticks = 'outside',
          tickcolor = 'black',
          tickwidth = 2,
          ticklen = 5,
          tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                          size = 10,
                          color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))


plot_ly(data, x = ~year,
    y = ~amt,
    name= '',
    type='scatter',
    mode = 'lines+markers',
    line = list(color = toRGB('#964f4d')),
    marker = list(color = toRGB("#964f4d")))

layout(title = 'Pre-purchase financing poll',
   xaxis = layout.xaxis,
   yaxis = layout.yaxis)
```

The layout command isn't working, if someone knows why and what should I do I would appreciate the help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try add `%>%` between `plot_ly` and `layout`.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I am not very advanced in the whole plotly package. I can't tell you why it isn't working (I simply don't know), but I changed your code and I got an output!

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

year <- c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)
amt <- c(11, 16, 21, 27, 33, 37, 43, 54, 68, 94, 128, 170, 213, 258, 307, 348, 385)

data <- data.frame(year, amt)

data$year <- factor(data$year, levels = data[["year"]])

a <- list(title = "Years",
          showline = TRUE,
          showgrid = FALSE,
          showticklabels = TRUE,
          linecolor = 'black',
          linewidth = 1,
          autotick = FALSE,
          ticks = 'outside',
          tickcolor = 'black',
          tickwidth = 2,
          ticklen = 5,
          tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                          size = 10,
                          color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))

b <- list(title = "Years",
          showline = TRUE,
          showgrid = FALSE,
          showticklabels = TRUE,
          linecolor = 'black',
          linewidth = 1,
          autotick = FALSE,
          ticks = 'outside',
          tickcolor = 'black',
          tickwidth = 2,
          ticklen = 5,
          tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                          size = 10,
                          color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))


plot_ly(data, x = ~year,
    y = ~amt,
    name= '',
    type='scatter',
    mode = 'lines+markers',
    line = list(color = toRGB('#964f4d')),
    marker = list(color = toRGB("#964f4d"))) %>%
layout(title = 'Pre-purchase financing poll',
   xaxis = a,
   yaxis = b)
```

I'm sorry I can't help you with an explanation, but I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: It work to some extent but now all ticks from the y axis are on the 0 mark. Do you know why that is??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of the `%>%` piping described above

```
p <- plot_ly(
  type = "scatter",
  data = vep_wes_aff_rare_summary, 
  x = ~n, 
  y = ~mean_af
)%>%
layout(
  title = 'Styled Scatter',
  yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE),
  xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE)
)
```